# Matlab - create matrix from 3d scatter points

Tags: matlab

I have tracked moving particles in a 3D space by storing their spatial coordinates positions in vectors. I.e. for a given time I have:

```
particle_x;
particle_y;
patricle_z;
```

specifying the x,y and z coordinates of each tracked particle/point. I can easily visualize these using scatter3 in Matlab, but from this, I would like to make 2D cuts and visualize the spread of points coinciding with certain planes. My idea was to create a 3D matrix of the whole 3D space and simply fill in a value ('1') where a particle is identified. However, I'm not really sure how to do this in a good way...

Since scatter3 can visualize the points in 3D, there has to be some sort of 3D matrix saved in the background, or? Or does anyone have a good idea of how I could do this? Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

/David

Comment: If you take a look at any given plane, it is very unlikely many points will lie exactly on it. Would it be useful to see the *projection* of your data on that plane instead?

Comment: Or maybe look at the points lying **between** two parallel planes separated with epsilon distance

Comment: I think the best solution (so far) has been to add a plane, and on this find all points being within a specified distance to this plane. These I can then project onto this given plane. So so far it's some kind of a combination of your suggested hints...